# Pika - Handling RabbitMQ Connection Loss

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, pika

Suppose you create a channel and start consuming messages in it.

```
channel = get_channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue=QUEUE_NAME, durable=True)

channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
channel.basic_consume(callback, queue=QUEUE_NAME)
channel.start_consuming()
```

But somehow you lose the connection to the RabbitMQ server. When connection drops, you get a `ConnectionClosed` exception and the consumer stops. How should one handle connection loss in pika when in *consumer* mode?

Comment: So, when is the connection closed, and is there any error message as to why? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48523425/rabbitmq-basic-publish/48526666#48526666

Comment: @theMayer As I said, it throws a `ConnectionClosed` exception. And since I stopped the server intentionally, it shows the "server shutdown" message in the exception object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up ditching `pika` and using `kombu` instead. You can build a robust consumer (which will reconnect if connection drops) as described in this article:

https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/building-robust-rabbitmq-consumers-with-python-and-kombu-part-1-ccd660d17271