# RabbitMQ basic publish

Tags: python, c++, rabbitmq

I have RabbitMQ listener written in Python from examples from rabbitmq's docs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time

import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hound')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % (body,))
    time.sleep(5)
    print(" [x] Done")
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)

channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue='hound',
                      )

print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
channel.start_consuming()
```

And C++ client which tries to send message:

```
#include <SimpleAmqpClient/SimpleAmqpClient.h>

using namespace AmqpClient;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Channel::ptr_t channel;

  channel = Channel::Create("SERVER_HOST", SERVER_PORT,
                            "LOGIN", "PASS", "/");

  BasicMessage::ptr_t msg = BasicMessage::Create("HELLO!!!");
  channel->DeclareQueue("hound");
  channel->BasicPublish("", "hound", msg, true);
}
```

But when I sent message I got error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'AmqpClient::PreconditionFailedException'
  what():  channel error: 406: AMQP_QUEUE_DECLARE_METHOD caused: PRECONDITION_FAILED - parameters for queue 'hound' in vhost '/' not equivalent
Aborted
```

But! When i delete line: `channel->DeclareQueue("hound");` successfully sent.

Sender writte in Python is working well:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import pika

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(
            username=username, password=password
        )

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
            pika.ConnectionParameters(
                host=host,
                virtual_host=virtual_host,
                credentials=credentials,
                port=RABBIT_PORT
            )
        )

channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='hound')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='hound',
                      body='hello!')
print(" [x] Sent %r" % (message,))
```

What's wrong? Why c++ client show me this error?

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by the fact that you are attempting to [re-declare a queue with different parameters](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html).

As the documentation states, a queue declaration is intended to be an [idempotent assertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) - if the queue does not exist, it is created. If it does exist, but has different parameters, you get this error.

> **Declaration and Property Equivalence**
>
> Before a queue can be used it has to be declared. Declaring a queue
>   will cause it to be created if it does not already exist. The
>   declaration will have no effect if the queue does already exist and
>   its attributes are the same as those in the declaration. When the
>   existing queue attributes are not the same as those in the declaration
>   a channel-level exception with code 406 (PRECONDITION_FAILED) will be
>   raised.

Something is going on in your `DeclareQueue("hound");` method that is different from `channel.queue_declare(queue='hound')`. Since we don't have the code for that, it is impossible to explain further, but I think this is sufficient information for you to solve the problem.

Comment: So I've solved promleb. It was becouse of all paramters in python's pika client are false but in c++ last two parametrs are true. When I changed in c++ client to: channel->DeclareQueue("hound", false, false, false, false); error is gone.